# MSTest: how to launch tests in few threads

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mstest

How to enable VisualStudio to run MSTests in parallel in few different threads?

I've found some manual for that:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

But I don't have 'Execution' node in my 'LocalTestRun.testrunconfig' file. Probably, I need to add this node myself? Or add it into another file?

Please advise.

P.S. I am working under VS20008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of that linked article says: "In Visual Studio 2010, we introduced the ability to run tests in parallel. "

As far as I know in VS 2008 there is no way to do this.